# NaN or Inf arrays preallocation

Tags: arrays, octave, pre-allocation

Array indexing can be used for [efficient array preallocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Advanced-Indexing.html#Advanced-Indexing). For instance

```
2(ones(1, 3))
ans =

   2   2   2
```

but this does not work with NaN or Inf

```
NaN(ones(1, 3))
ans = NaN
```

Why ?

Answer (score 3):

`NaN` and `Inf` look like special variables, when used without parenthesis.

But they are [actually functions](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/NaN.html).

`NaN(ones (1, 3))` expands to `NaN ([1, 1, 1])` which apparently is evaluated like `NaN (1, 1, 1)`. That is to a `1x1x1` array, which has only a single element.

The correct way to initialize a 1x3 NaN array is

```
NaN (1, 3)
```

Same for `Inf`.

---

Following @carandraug suggestion, here is a slight *digression*.

One might also use `NaN ()(ones(1, 3))`.

In this expression, `NaN ()` evaluates to the `NaN` scalar value (not a function anymore). `ones(1, 3)` evaluates to `[1, 1, 1]`.

So an intermediate step could be read as `<NaN scalar value>([1 1 1])`.

Then remember [how indexing works](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Advanced-Indexing.html#Advanced-Indexing).
Indexing of an array `A` with an array of integers `indexes` is written `A(indexes)`. For instance

```
A([i1, i2, i3])
```

This prepares an array of the same size as `indexes` (1x3 here). Each element of this new array will get the value of the element of `A` having the index given by the corresponding element of `indexes`. That is

```
[A(i1), A(i2), A(i3)]
```

So the result of `2(ones (1, 3))`, i.e. `2([1, 1, 1])` is obviously `[2(1), 2(1), 2(1)]`. i.e. `[2, 2, 2]`. 
(Remembering that a scalar can be interpreted as a single element array. So `2(1)` means first element of the array `[2]`, which is `2`).

Similarly, the intermediate step `<NaN scalar value>([1 1 1])` is finally transformed in

```
[<NaN scalar value>, <NaN scalar value>, <NaN scalar value>]
```

or simply `[NaN, NaN, NaN]`.

Comment: Might be worth to explain the other side, how the same syntax could be made to work with `Inf` and `NaN`, e.g., `Inf ()(ones (1, 3))`.

Comment: Or maybe `NaN(size(ones(1,3)))` even though it's superfluous. @carandraug: `Inf ()(ones (1, 3))` is invalid Matlab. Not sure what you're suggesting.

Comment: @horchler I was just suggesting that it would be a nice addition (from an educational POV only) to explain why `2([1 1 1])` works and show the exact same syntax with `Inf ()([1 1 1])`. Again, only educational, the answer is correct as it is. Also, this an Octave question not tagged with Matlab so being invalid Matlab should not be an issue.